# How to find the information from google search result

Tags: python-3.x, search, google-custom-search

I want to get the information from google search result. I have some keywords and want to extract information from keywords related pages by python script.

Answer (score 0):

well you can always use tools like scrapy to crawl through the page, but, google also offers APIs for search. have you seen https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview ?

complete your question and add more details about what you exactly need, you'll get more accurate answers.